# A likes B, but B does not like A?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If my table, called Table, looks like this:

```
A B
1 2
3 2
2 1
etc...
```

This would imply 1 likes 2, 3 likes 2, and 2 likes 1...assuming its a lot bigger than this, how do I write an SQL query where I report where A likes B, but B does not like A?

So for this case, an example output should be:

```
3 2
```

Because 3 likes 2 from the relation, but 2 does not like 3.

Comment: What does "likes" mean exactly? Can you give some sample output?

Comment: Don't call your table "Table". Call it "likes".

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT A, B
  FROM likes x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM likes
                    WHERE x.A = B AND x.B = A)
```

Comment: That would cut down the query time, but I don't think it will find all of the desired results!

Comment: @chezy525, yes of course you are right. Sorry, wrong thinking.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. The EXISTS subquery is correlated, in MySQL, LEFT JOIN is definitely faster; not sure about PostgreSQL.

Comment: i tried it on a larger scale, and it produced errors.. :( still, nice attempt

Comment: Huh, just read through the comments here again, and noticed that @linepogl deleted the first comment, which I was responding to, about a method of speeding this query up.  Now, it looks like I'm incorrectly criticizing this answer... which I'm not because this should give the correct results, and in some cases, faster than my answer.

Comment: @chezy525: Yeah, I noticed that too, though I'm sure most people would figure it out pretty quickly. You can avoid such confusion by always prefixing comments with the addressee (as I've just done).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use a `left join` (Disclaimer: I use SQL Server not postgresql)

```
select l.A, l.B
from likes l
  left join likes nl on l.B=nl.A and l.A=nl.B
where nl.A is null
```

Comment: can you actually explain this a bit for me please?

Comment: Basically, I start with finding the opposite result set (i.e. records where A likes B and B also likes A).  This can be done with a simple `join` (`SELECT l.A, l.B FROM likes l JOIN likes l2 on l.B=l2.A and l.A=l2.B`).  Then, you need to get the results that aren't in that set: the `left join` keeps the records that don't "match", and the `where` clause removes the records that do "match".